# In iOS7, chrome & safari, on focus of an input field, the page scrolls. How do I stop that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-chrome, safari

In iOS7, chrome and safari, on focus of an input field, the page scrolls.

I want the field to be focused if the user taps inside it and I want scrolling to still work, but the default scrolling that happens on input field focus, I want that to stop.

How can I do that?

Here is a sample JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6HvUh/

Code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $('input').animate({'top':100});
});
```

Comment: Do you have any source/example? JSFiddle?

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen I updated the question with a sample fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS safari will always try to center the focused input in the center of the visible screen. That, combined with `position: fixed`, which is a bit buggy in iOS, can cause strange effects.

My advice is, if possible, not to use `position: fixed`. You can change your page this way:

1. wrap your text, or everything scrollable, in a div with class 'scrollable'.
2. Change the position of your inputs to `absolute` (or the position of their container).
3. Add some CSS:

   div.scrollable
   { 
       width: 100%; 
       height: 100%; 
       overflow: auto;
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
   }

   ```
   html, body 
   { 
       width: 100%; 
       height: 100%; 
       overflow: hidden; 
   }
   ```

Be aware that your inputs can *never* be hidden by the keyboard. If you put inputs near the bottom of the page you'll see scroll anyway.